# REINDEX not using all available resources, running forever

Tags: postgresql-performance, azure

I have an Azure Database for Postgresql Single server instance, which is running PostgreSQL v11.

In it, I have a table responsible for gathering the metrics regarding user logins. The table definition is as follows:

```
 table_name  |      column_name      |        data_type         
-------------+-----------------------+--------------------------
 Logins      | Id                    | text
 Logins      | FirstA1LoginDate      | date
 Logins      | FirstA2LoginDate      | date
 Logins      | ConsentDate           | date
 Logins      | ConsentLevel          | text
 Logins      | FirstA1LoginTimestamp | timestamp with time zone
 Logins      | FirstA2LoginTimestamp | timestamp with time zone
 Logins      | ConsentTimestamp      | timestamp with time zone
 Logins      | LatestCode            | character varying
 Logins      | LatestProofLevel      | character varying
 Logins      | LatestLoginTimestamp  | timestamp with time zone
 Logins      | SingleLoginFlag       | character varying
 Logins      | OptedIn               | character varying
 Logins      | OptedInTimestamp      | timestamp with time zone
```

The table has these indices:

```
               indexname               |                                                     indexdef                                                      
---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      logins_optedintimestamp_idx      | CREATE INDEX logins_optedintimestamp_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("OptedInTimestamp")
      logins_firsta1logindate_idx      | CREATE INDEX logins_firsta1logindate_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("FirstA1LoginDate")
      logins_firsta2logindate_idx      | CREATE INDEX logins_firsta2logindate_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("FirstA2LoginDate")
      logins_consentdate_idx           | CREATE INDEX logins_consentdate_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("ConsentDate")
      logins_consenttimestamp_idx      | CREATE INDEX logins_consenttimestamp_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("ConsentTimestamp")
      logins_firsta1logintimestamp_idx | CREATE INDEX logins_firsta1logintimestamp_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("FirstA1LoginTimestamp")
      logins_firsta1logintimestamp_idx | CREATE INDEX logins_firsta2logintimestamp_idx ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("FirstA2LoginTimestamp")
      Logins_pkey                      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Logins_pkey" ON schema."Logins" USING btree ("Id")
```

The table contains 680m rows.

The server is configured to have 4 vCPUs, "can use up to" 9246 IOPS, and has 5GB memory per vCore (so, 20GB total).

I want to REINDEX Logins, so I took a copy of the entire database to do tests on. As such, my load is the only load being induced on the database. I ran the following:

```
REINDEX TABLE schema."Logins"
```

After a while (looks like about 4 hours going by the CPU, IO, and memory utilisation graph in Azure) it timed out:

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Guessing that I need to invest more time, I researched a little about Postgres performance, and made the following changes:

```
 SET maintenance_work_mem TO 2097151; -- was 256MB
 ALTER TABLE Logins SET (parallel_workers = 4); -- was 2
 SET max_parallel_maintenance_workers TO 4; -- was 4
```

I did not change these values:

```
 checkpoint_timeout: 5min
 statement_timeout: 0
 autovacuum: on
```

After restarting the REINDEX (this time with (VERBOSE) to see if that gives me some info):

```
 REINDEX (VERBOSE) TABLE Logins;
```

I monitored utilisation of the CPU, IO, and memory for 30 mins:

[image: Resource utilisation during REINDEX]

It seems like there's a lot of headroom that could be utilised to speed up the process. What else can I change to make use of *all* the resources?